# My ajax response not showing into my dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am trying to show my ajax json response into data table.
I am using datatable AJAX option but nothing is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#example').dataTable( {
            "ajax": {
            "url": "https://2057-185-202-239-227.ngrok.io/serviceprovider/billByServiceProvider",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function ( d ) {
            return JSON.stringify( d.serviceProvider = sessionStorage.getItem("Services_id") );
             },
             "dataSrc": function(json){
                console.log(json);
             }
         }
    }); 
    });
```

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: Does your URL work? What is it returning when you send the request? Are there any errors in your browser console? Please post this information too otherwise "nothing is working" does not really say anything.

Comment: I believe you (or someone with the same user name as you) already asked this question here: [Api response to data table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71885609/12567365). Instead of asking what is effectively a duplicate question, you can edit the original question to show the updated attempt.

Comment: it wasnt me @andrewJames.

Comment: @n1md7 Its showing nothing. Nor its appending any data to my data table. Ithink I have issues in my ajax call or something

Comment: You can monitor what request is leaving your browser window from the network tab and see the response and compare whether or not the response data is something you expect. Maybe it's not event sending anything

Comment: @n1md7 sir its not sending any request I dont know what wrong with the request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.